# Android - staying in app after call has been made

Tags: android, call

I want to be able to make calls from my app. I understand how to make a call from an app. The problem is that I don't want to redirect the user after the call is made.

As far as I understand this code is used to make a call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that a user is then redirected to a default caller app(don't know how its called). I want the user to stay in my app when the call is active.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

With this code you do not make call from you app, you start the default app for calling a number. If you do not want to use the default application, you have to implement the phone calling by yourself (which I do not reccomend, by the way, but you can do it if you need to).

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/phone/PhoneApp.java#PhoneApp.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) is the default caller application of android, you have to make something similar (and make it up to date by time).

Also you can register for call made by any other appication by putting this intent-filter in you manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.Call"
    android:label="@string/makeCall" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution myself.

I used this code to make the call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

Then I made a call state listener which listens for the call to take place. Once the call is initiated i run this code to open my app's activity again:

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("IN_CALL", true);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The call is not canceled and still runs in the background.

I think it's a pretty simple solution to my problem because I don't need to rewrite the caller app and I can still use the basic features of the caller app. Like hanging up, putting my phone to speaker mode, etc.

Comment: oh I was misunderstanding you, I tought you want to stay in your app during the call

Comment: That was the initial plan, but making a custom caller app seemed to advanced for me. With this code im able to make a call through the default caller and the user will not leave my app and will be able to interact with the call through my app.

Comment: oh, than I don't understand why did you take back the pipe, because to your original question I have the answer.

Comment: I'm confused... In your answer you said that in order to implement calling to my app I have to make a new caller app. Which I don't know how since the default caller app uses some internal android libraries which I can't access.
Maybe I misunderstood you. Can you tell me more about your answer ?